# Delphi SMTP component that supports UTF-8 or Unicode

Tags: delphi, unicode, smtp, delphi-2009, indy

It [appears](https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?messageID=43720) the Indy 10 SMTP component shipped with Delphi 2009 do not properly support unicode in the subject and body.

Does anyone know of a good alternative, or has anyone made the necessary changes to Indy10 to solve this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question, the "or" does not make much sense. To quote Wikipedia: "UTF-8 (8-bit UCS/Unicode Transformation Format) is a variable-length character encoding for Unicode". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the suggestions, I think I've found a component that really works.  Its an ActiveX rather than Delphi component, but does the trick. Nice and simple.

The component is The  [Chilkat SMTP component](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/email-activex.asp) .  The [code example here](http://www.example-code.com/delphi/delphi-japanese-email.asp) does exactly what I want and it works!!!

Comment: Thanks Francisco would you like to elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

I would also note that most mail servers may not handle Unicode properly in the mail subject line.  I haven't seen any real statistics on this, but my guess is that a very healthy percentage of mail servers still expect ascii subject lines as I believe that's what the RFC's define.

(The message body can of course be encoded to ensure it goes through.)

Comment: This is why you might want a component that could take your UTF-8 data and automatically format it for sending via SMTP -- see http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=692745

Comment: RFC 2047 defines how to put non-ASCII characters in the ASCII-only subject. http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2047.html

Answer (score 3):

You can check out this solution with Indy 10 (tested on russian charsets)

http://dev-doc.blogspot.com/2012/08/delphi-indy-10-ssl-and-encoding-issues.html

Answer (score 2):

Indy 10 has been updated since D2009's initial release to handle Unicode better now.  Have a look at the current Tiburon snapshot in Indy's SVN.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely look at IPWorks from nSoftware.com.  Their latest version is supposed to be fully Delphi 2009 compliant.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at [Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download) which does properly handle unicode in the subject and body.  You will need to download the repository via the [SVN](https://synalist.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/synalist/trunk/) repository, which is more up to date than the version listed for download on the website.  The SVN version includes support for Delphi 2009.

Comment: Can you explain how Synapse "properly" handles Unicode in the subject line?  How does it work with 7-bit servers?

Comment: I would imagine it simply follows RFC 2047.

Comment: Follows the RFC 2047 specifications by properly encoding the subject line.  I have many customers who use my product to support various other character sets and it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 1):

EasyMail says it supports RFC 2047 which Rob mentioned as handling non-ascii subject lines:

http://www.componentsource.com/products/easymail-objects/summary.html

Answer (score 0):

A bug was recently discovered in Indy 10's IdHeaderoderUTF class that would prevent UTF-7 and UTF-8 from working properly when encoding email headers that have Unicode characters in them.